# Datetime field default `now()` causes "value not of required type" error?

Tags: formula, customsetting, default-value

Per [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/16067/149), and everything I know about Salesforce formulas, if I want the default value of a datetime field to be the current time, I should be able to use the formula `now()`.  In this case, the field is on a Hierarchal Custom Setting, but the principle is the same.  The formula editor will accept the formula, but when I go to the Manage page and click "New" to create the org-wide custom setting, I get an error:

> There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Last Run Time: value not of required type: Fri Aug 31 16:18:48 GMT 2018".

So even though `now()` returns a Datetime, it's getting treated like a string.  I also tried changing the formula to `DateTimeValue(now())`, but get the same result.  Is this a bug or am I overlooking something?

**Edit**: to clarify, I have a Hierarchy-type custom setting, with a field named Last_Run_Time__c of type DateTime.  I wish to enforce a default value of the current time.  I set the default value formula to `now()`, and the system accepted that value.  When I try to create the org-wide instance of the custom setting (Custom Setting -> Manage -> New), I get the validation error quoted above.  Why does using `now()` to set the default value of this field result in this error?  `now()` is documented to return a `Datetime`, not a string.

Comment: Its worth raising with SF, This works fine with Sobject and Custom Metadata Types. I cant figure out a reason why this would be different for custom setting.

Comment: Still an issue 5 years later :(